# using scrapy for multiple search options based website

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and Python.

I would like to scrape a property registar's website which uses a query based search. Most of the examples I have seen use simple web pages, not using search via the FormRequest mechanism.  The code I have written is below.  Everything is currently hardcoded. I would like to be able to scrape the data base on the year or county .

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class SecondSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "second"

    '''
    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/pprweb.nsf/PPR?OpenForm"# this is the form here it asks for the following,
                                    # then the linke changes to this form
                                   https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/PPR/npsra-ppr.nsf/PPR-By-Date?SearchView
                                   &Start=1
                                   &SearchMax=0
                                   &SearchOrder=4
                                   &Query=%5Bdt_execution_date%5D%3E=01/01/2010%20AND%20%5Bdt_execution_date%5D%3C01/01/2011
                                   &County=                 # this are the fields of query
                                   &Year=2010               # this are the fields of query
                                   &StartMonth=             # this are the fields of query
                                   &EndMonth=               # this are the fields of query
                                   &Address=                # this are the fields of query

                                   formdata={'user': 'john', 'pass': 'secret'},
                                   callback=self.logged_in)]

    def logged_in(self, response):
        # here you would extract links to follow and return Requests for
        # each of them, with another callback
        pass
    '''
    allowed_domains = ["www.propertypriceregister.ie"]
    start_urls = ('https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/pprweb.nsf/PPR?OpenForm',)

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='/website/npsra/PPR/npsra-ppr.nsf/PPR-By-Date?SearchView&Start=1&SearchMax=0&SearchOrder=4&Query=%5Bdt_execution_date%5D%3E=01/01/2010%20AND%20%5Bdt_execution_date%5D%3C01/01/2011&County=&Year=2010&StartMonth=&EndMonth=&Address='),
            callback='parse',
            follow= True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        print response
        pass
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  I'd recommend you spend more time formatting your question properly, as it was submitted with horrible indentation, and (still) includes a lot of redundant/commented out code.  If you can't be bothered to put effort into asking the question, no one will bother putting effort into answering it!

Comment: Thank you rejected for your feedback , i will make sure i will have the question formatted and put in the requisite effort to make sure the question is clearly formatted. apologies for the poor quality of question .

Answer (score 1):

Before you get started, re-read how [`Rule`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/spiders.html?highlight=start_requests#crawling-rules) objects work.  At present, your rule will match a very-specific URL which the site will never show a link for (as it's in the format of a form post).

Next, don't override the `parse` function of the CrawlSpider (actually, don't use it at all).  It's used internally by the CrawlSpider to function (see the warning on the link I provided for additional details).

You'll need to generate a `FormRequest` for each of the elements to be called, similar to something like this (*note: untested, but it should work*):

```
import itertools
... # all your other imports here

class SecondSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'second'
    allowed_domains = ['propertypriceregister.ie', 'www.propertypriceregister.ie']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("/eStampUNID/UNID-")), callback='parse_search'),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]
        counties = ['County1', 'County2')
        for county, year in itertools.product(*[counties, years]):
            yield scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/pprweb.nsf/PPR?OpenForm",
                                      formdata={'County': county, 'Year': year}, 
                                      dont_filter=True)

    def parse_search(self, response):
        # Parse response here
```

From this point, your rule(s) will be applied to each of the pages you get back from the FormRequest to pull URLs from it.  If you want to actually grab anything from those initial urls, override the `parse_start_url` method of the CrawlSpider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i will implement it and post the result